# How to prove that $L_{D}\leq L_{U}$?

Tags: computability, reductions

I have the following two languages:
$$
L_{U}\triangleq\left\{ \langle M,x\rangle\,:\,M\text{ accepts }x\right\} ,L_{D}\triangleq\left\{ \langle M\rangle\,:\,M\text{ accepts }\langle M\rangle\right\} 
$$
I'm trying to prove that $L_{D}\leq L_{U}$. For that I need to show that there exists $f\,:\,\Sigma^{*}\to\Sigma^{*}$ total, can be calculated by a Turing machine and follows: $\forall x\in\Sigma^*$, $x\in L_D$ iff $f(x)\in L_U$.

Let there be $f\,:\,\Sigma^{*}\to\Sigma^{*}$ so $f\left(\langle M\rangle\right)=\langle M,M\rangle$. I have proved that $f$ is total and also follows the last condition. All that left to do is to prove that $f$ can be calculated by a Turing machine. How should I describe the steps of machine $M_f$ on $\langle M\rangle$?

Answer (score 0):

It is the turing machine that clones its input. If you want a description of this machine's operation, you may find [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/91396/how-would-you-create-a-turing-machine-that-copies-a-string-and-prints-it-to-the) useful.